# Convert any string to hex in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, hex

Is there a way to convert any possible string value to hex in VB.net.

For instance, I've tried this:

```
 Convert.ToInt32("hello", 16)
```

But this throws an error saying "Could not find any recognizable digits".

I would like it to return `68656c6c6f`, which is a hex representation of the characters in the string.

Comment: What would you expect to be the result of that function?

Comment: This website returns 68656c6c6f. http://string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the bytes of the string and then convert each byte to a string.  The easiest (but not most efficient way) would be something like this:

```
Private Function GetHexString(Source As String) As String
    Dim b As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Source)
    Return BitConverter.ToString(b).Replace("-", "")
End Function
```

Comment: Know this wasn't part of the original question, but how would I go about converting this result back to the original string?

Would I just need to call System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b)?