# VB.NET Substring function broken

Tags: vb.net, substring

I have a problem with Substring function. As you can see on [Watch window shcreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbfsz.png) I have the variable called **val** equal to ‎**03.‎09.‎2015 ‏‎17:30**

I do not understand why but

```
val.Substring(0,2) returns 0 instead of 03
val.Substring(0,3) returns 03 (string of two symbols)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you clicked on the "reload" button for both of the expression?

Comment: Btw, you should not use string methods to parse this `Date` but `Date.Parse`/`Date.ParseExact`/`Date.TryParse`/`Date.TryParseExact`. Then you have all you need(for example the date, hours, minutes etc.)

Comment: Yes, I reloaded expressions

Comment: Upon pasting your value to dotnet fiddle, turns out you have invisible characters there https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZEsy3n

Comment: The original problem was with Parse (and Parse-like) functions. It can not parse this string as Date or DateTime

Comment: You can remove the nonprintable character https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259275/removing-hidden-characters-from-within-strings so it can be parsed by DateTime parser

Answer (score 3):

Your string contains non-printable characters. Note the following from your screenshot:

```
val = "03.09.2015 17:30"
val.Length = 21
```

However, `03.09.2015 17:30` only has 16 characters. Thus, the string contains other, zero-width characters.

To find the culprit, output a [hex dump](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28308904/87698) of your problematic string and compare it with the hex dump of the literal string `03.09.2015 17:30`.

Comment: The non-printable chars are even present in the string in the question (at least four of them are).

Answer (score 0):

From OP comment:

*The original problem was with Parse (and Parse-like) functions. It can not parse this string as Date or DateTime*

Once the invisible characters are removed from the string, it certainly can be parsed:

```
Dim d As Date = DateTime.Parse("03.09.2015 17:30", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim m As Integer = d.Month    ' m = 3
```

Of course, choose the particular Parse method that best fits your needs.